# Single layout file and single java file for Both Activity and it's Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-studio

Is it a good approach to define both the activity and fragment layout in the same .xml file like this?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.vitealth.android.LoginActivityPatient"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.vitealth.android.LoginActivityPatient$LoginActivityFragment"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="#ff8cc86a">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.7">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="1156dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/pockedoc_login"
                android:id="@+id/icon_login"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:cropToPadding="false" />
        </FrameLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.3">
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Invalid_indicator_tv"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Username"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:background="#26454545"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                android:id="@+id/username_textbox"
                style="@style/EditTextTheme"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Password"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:background="#26454545"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:password="true"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                style="@style/EditTextTheme"
                android:id="@+id/password_textbox"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Login as Patient"
                android:id="@+id/login_button_patient"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:backgroundTint="#fff43d2c"
                />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sign Up as Patient"
                android:textColor="#ff3348ff"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/signup_button_patient"
                android:backgroundTint="#fffdfdfd" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

if yes, then why does android studio, by default, make separate files for them if you make activity with fragments?

Similarly, would it be wise to make a single java file for both activity and fragment? Why?

Comment: I would think that it is better to separate them for readability, and also because it is what Android apparently recommends. This question's answers will all be based on opinions though.

Comment: What if you want make a fragment that runs on multiple activities. Would this approach be valid in that case?

Comment: I think fragments are supposed to be unique to activities, but honestly I don't have much insight on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

obviously, it is not good to have activity and fragment layout in the same .xml

**Why?**

Because why use fragment when your activity contains the same layout which is there in fragment XML.also if you use this type of views then your activity be used for the only specific to that fragment views only which is not the actual use of fragment.you can't add any other fragment in that activity if you do as you mentioned